# .filter is not working to filter from json response using javascript on my server

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I am filtering data from json response using .filter() function. It is working fine on my local system but when I uploaded my code on server I am getting error `respose.filter is not a function`

My code is:

```
$.get( 'js/question.json', function(response) {
    var newres = response.filter(function(x){ return x.difficulty == q_id; });
    if(last_id!='')
        newres = newres.filter(function(y){ return y.id != last_id; });

    newres = shuffle(newres);

    level_e1 = newres[0].question;
    console.log(level_e1);
    level_left_e1 = newres[0].type;
    questionId = newres[0].id;

    CopyOfInit();

    correct_answer = 0;
    wrong_answer = 0;
});

response is

[{
    "id": "5402",
    "question": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "answer": "1",
    "difficulty": "1",
    "game_name": "Alphabet",
    "notes": "Drag and drop alphabet cards to the empty slots",
    "question_id": "13CA9999",
    "question_type": "A B C",
    "type": "left1_e1"
}, {
    "id": "5403",
    "question": ["b", "c", "d"],
    "answer": "1",
    "difficulty": "1",
    "game_name": "Alphabet",
    "notes": "Drag and drop alphabet cards to the empty slots",
    "question_id": "13CA9998",
    "question_type": "B C D",
    "type": "left1_e1"
}]
```

What could be the issue here?
Is this my hosting server issue or something wrong in my code?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse(response)` before `filter()` ? `filter` is an `Array prototype` function not working on plain strings...

Comment: In other words, `response` or is not an `Array`.

Comment: response is json objects

Comment: Double check your spelling. Your error says "respose.filter" but your code says "response.filter". Which is the right one?

Comment: @Vinie - you are using `$.get()` to be sure you actually get JSON you could use `$.getJSON()`

Comment: @Andy sorry for that that is my typo mistake

Comment: Thank you @davidkonrad `$.getJSON()` solved my problem